# Difference between 2 way of serialization in the Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core-development, serialization

This [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/114357/101040), explains what are `SERIALIZE_METHODS` and `DESERIALIZE_METHODS` macros in the Bitcoin Core. They prevent duplicate code for implementing the serialization and deserialization logic. But I've seen some classes in the Bitcoin Core which do the serialization differently. [Here's](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/v24.0/src/coins.h#L60) an example:

```
/**
 * A UTXO entry.
 *
 * Serialized format:
 * - VARINT((coinbase ? 1 : 0) | (height << 1))
 * - the non-spent CTxOut (via TxOutCompression)
 */
class Coin
{

    ...

    template<typename Stream>
    void Serialize(Stream &s) const {
        assert(!IsSpent());
        uint32_t code = nHeight * uint32_t{2} + fCoinBase;
        ::Serialize(s, VARINT(code));
        ::Serialize(s, Using<TxOutCompression>(out));
    }

    template<typename Stream>
    void Unserialize(Stream &s) {
        uint32_t code = 0;
        ::Unserialize(s, VARINT(code));
        nHeight = code >> 1;
        fCoinBase = code & 1;
        ::Unserialize(s, Using<TxOutCompression>(out));
    }
```

So, what's the difference between these two way of implementing serializing and deserializing methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing.

The `SERIALIZE_METHODS` approach lets one write the serialization and deserialization code at once, but it effectively is just a (possibly) simplified way of writing the `Serialize` and `Unserialize` functions.

In this example, the author of the code just chose to write those functions directly and separately.